# This javascript isn't working offline

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a gadget system in javascript like Win7 Sidebar, but this isn't working in the FILE protocol. The browser I'm using is Chrome.
How can I make it to work offline?

```js
var selected = null, // Object of the element to be moved
    x_pos = 0, y_pos = 0, // Stores x & y coordinates of the mouse pointer
    x_elem = 0, y_elem = 0; // Stores top, left values (edge) of the element

// Will be called when user starts dragging an element
function _drag_init(elem) {
    // Store the object of the element which needs to be moved
    selected = elem;
    x_elem = x_pos ;
    y_elem = y_pos;
}

// Will be called when user dragging an element
function _move_elem(e) {
    x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
    y_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;
    if (selected !== null) {
        selected.style.left = (x_pos - x_elem) + 'px';
        selected.style.top = (y_pos - y_elem) + 'px';
    }
}

// Destroy the object when we are done
function _destroy() {
    selected = null;
}

// Bind the functions...
var draggables = document.getElementsByClassName('draggable-element');
for(var i = 0; i < draggables.length; i++){
  draggables[i].onmousedown = function () {
      _drag_init(this);
      return false;
  };
}

document.onmousemove = _move_elem;
document.onmouseup = _destroy;
```

```css
body {padding:10px}

.draggable-element {
  width:125px;
  height:125px;
  background-color:#666;
  color:white;
  padding:10px 12px;
  cursor:move;
  position:relative; /* important (all position that's not `static`) */
}
```

```html
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
```

For who can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Could u provide your full html code? Maybe there's something weird there.

Comment: `[...]but this isn't working [...]` is not a really helpful information. Do you see any error message in the console? Does nothing happen or does it behave in a different way then expected?

Comment: You stated that it doesn't work on the FILE protocol, does this mean that it works on HTTP, or not at all?

Comment: People can run the code snippet, and see that it works. But when built into a single html file (using script and style tags) in the FILE protocol it don't works. Only works via HTTP, like seen in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `_move_elem` function with this:

```
function _move_elem(e) {
    x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
    y_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;
    if (selected !== null) {
        selected.style.left = (x_pos) + 'px';
        selected.style.top = (y_pos) + 'px';
    }
}
```

I think subtracting the position is throwing it off, putting it back to the start.  I am using file uri as well, and it works. Hope this helps!
EDIT: Codepen at http://codepen.io/JohnJ1101/pen/oZpwGv

Comment: Please share all the javascript. I can't understand it exactly.

Comment: The console is empty.

Comment: What OS? Latest chrome? I am using Windows 8.1 and latest chrome (x64), try updating

Comment: Windows 7 SP1 64bit. Latest Chrome (x64).